# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lbr.com.jcom.modelo.Marca;

Tags: java

Estou com o seguinte erro :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lbr.com.jcom.modelo.Marca;
    at br.com.jcom.dao.MarcaDao.insert(MarcaDao.java:1)
    at br.com.jcom.facade.DaoFacade.insert(DaoFacade.java:21)
    at br.com.jcom.controller.MarcaController.addMarca(MarcaController.java:19)
    at br.com.jcom.gui.MarcaGUI$3.actionPerformed(MarcaGUI.java:145)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Só que é assim, quando faço o *insert* direto pela `MarcaDAO`:

```java
MarcaDao marcadao = new MarcaDao();
marcadao.insert(marca);
```

Funciona normalmente.

Mas quando passo pela *controller*, que passa para o *façade*, apresenta o erro acima:

```java
int result = 0;

                if (idMarca == null) {
                    System.out.println("ADD");
                    result = new MarcaController().addMarca(marca);
                } else {
                    marca.setMarcaID(idMarca);
                    result = new MarcaController().updateMarca(marca);
                    idMarca = null;
                }
```

Então o erro não dá na `MarcaDAO`.

Subi o projeto no mega, para quem puder me ajudar dar uma olhada. Tem o banco de dados em SQLServer 2005 também.

link: https://mega.co.nz/#!Pp1kGAhL!e7G1NF6T6zcMPKAdZlHof8Eyw48fppR_SsFJY-2Zw7M

`MarcaDao`:

```java
package br.com.jcom.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import br.com.jcom.factory.Conexao;
import br.com.jcom.modelo.Marca;

public class MarcaDao implements IDao<Marca> {

    private String nomeTabela = "Marcas";
    private Connection connection;

    public MarcaDao() {
        this.connection = new Conexao().getConnection();

    }

    @Override
    public String getNomeTabela() {
        return nomeTabela;
    }

    @Override
    public int insert(Marca... elementos) {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO " + nomeTabela + " (marca) VALUES (?)";
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        int result = 0;

        for (Marca marca : elementos) {
            try {
                stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                stmt.setString(1, marca.getMarca());
                result = stmt.executeUpdate();

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally{
                Conexao.close(connection, stmt, null);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Marca... elementos) {

        String sql = "UPDATE " + nomeTabela + "SET marca = ? WHERE MarcaID = ?";
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        int result = 0;

        for (Marca marca : elementos) {
            try {
                stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                stmt.setString(1, marca.getMarca());
                stmt.setLong(2, marca.getMarcaID());
                result = stmt.executeUpdate();

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                Conexao.close(connection, stmt, null);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Marca... elementos) {

        String sql = "DELETE FROM " + nomeTabela + "WHERE MarcaID = ?";
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        int result = 0;

        for (Marca marca : elementos) {
            try {
                stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                stmt.setLong(1, marca.getMarcaID());
                result = stmt.executeUpdate();

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                Conexao.close(connection, stmt, null);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Marca> selectAll() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + nomeTabela;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        List<Marca> marcas = new ArrayList<Marca>();
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Marca marca = new Marca();
                marca.setMarcaID(rs.getLong("marcaID"));
                marca.setMarca(rs.getString("marca"));

                marcas.add(marca);

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            Conexao.close(connection, stmt, rs);
        }
        return marcas;

    }

}
```

`IDao`:

```java
package br.com.jcom.dao;

import java.util.List;

public interface IDao<T> {

    String getNomeTabela();

    int insert(T... elementos);

    int update(T... elementos);

    int delete(T... elementos);

    //T selectCodigo(String codigo);

    //T select(String sql, String... paramentros);

    List<T> selectAll();

    // List<T> selectAll(String sql, String... paramentros);

}
```

`DaoFacade`:

```java
package br.com.jcom.facade;

import java.util.List;

import br.com.jcom.dao.IDao;
import br.com.jcom.modelo.Marca;

public class DaoFacade<T> {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private IDao dao;

    public DaoFacade(IDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public int insert(Marca marca) {
        return dao.insert(marca);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public int update(T... elementos) {
        return dao.update(elementos);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public int delete(T... elementos) {
        return dao.delete(elementos);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> selectAll() {
        return dao.selectAll();

    }

}
```

`Marca` (modelo):

```java
package br.com.jcom.modelo;

public class Marca {

    private Long marcaID;
    private String marca;

    public Marca() {
        super();
    }

    public Marca(Long marcaID, String marca) {
        super();
        this.marcaID = marcaID;
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    public Long getMarcaID() {
        return marcaID;
    }

    public void setMarcaID(Long marcaID) {
        this.marcaID = marcaID;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }

}
```

`MarcaController`:

```java
package br.com.jcom.controller;

import java.util.List;

import br.com.jcom.dao.MarcaDao;
import br.com.jcom.facade.DaoFacade;
import br.com.jcom.modelo.Marca;

public class MarcaController {

    private DaoFacade marcaFacade;

    public MarcaController() {
        this.marcaFacade = new DaoFacade<Marca>(new MarcaDao());
    }

    public int addMarca(Marca marca) {
        return marcaFacade.insert(marca);

    }

    public int updateMarca(Marca marca) {
        return marcaFacade.update(marca);

    }

    public int deleteMarca(Marca marca) {
        return marcaFacade.delete(marca);

    }

    public List<Marca> selectMarcas() {
        return marcaFacade.selectAll();

    }

}
```

Chamada `MarcaGUI` botão salvar:

```java
btnSalvar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Marca marca = new Marca();

            if (Funcoes.validaCampos(panel) == true) {
                marca.setMarca(tfMarca.getText());
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Preenchimento de campos (*) obrigatórios");
                return;
            }

            int result = 0;

            if (idMarca == null) {
                new MarcaController().addMarca(marca);
            } else {
                marca.setMarcaID(idMarca);
                result = new MarcaController().updateMarca(marca);
                idMarca = null;
            }

            if (result == 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Concluido");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao salvar");
            }

            refreshTable();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Poste a FACADE, com o construtor e o método insert, o método insert da MarcaDao e como está a criar as respetivas instâncias.

Comment: Editei o post..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sempre que há um `warning`, algo não vai bem no código, no seu caso o compiler tentou te avisar mas você ignorou.
Seu problema é `varargs` com `generics`, Esse `varargs` do parâmetro é convertido em um `array de Object`, que falha no `cast` para Marca e resulta no `ClassCastException`. [Esse artigo](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ300) tem um relato e explicação detalhada.

> Conclusion:  It is probably best to avoid providing objects of
>   non-reifiable types where a variable argument list is expected.  You
>   will always receive an unchecked warning and unless you know exactly
>   what the invoked method does you can never be sure that the invocation
>   is type-safe.

---

> Conclusão: É provavelmente o melhor para evitar a prestação de objetos
>   de tipos `non-reifiable` onde se espera uma lista de argumentos
>   variável. Você sempre receberá um aviso e se você não sabe exatamente
>   o que o método invocador faz, você nunca poderá ter certeza de que a
>   invocação é segura.

Comment: OK,  mas o que VC recomenda fazer entao?

Comment: como devo fazer então?

Comment: bom acho que entendi, substitui: "int insert(T... elementos);" por: "int insert(T elementos);"